# How to trigger email on woocommerce order status change?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I have created a custom order status on functions.php called `Packed`.
How do I send a custom email when the order status changes from `Processing` to `Packed`?

I tried using the below code but for some reason its not working.

```
   add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_recipient_packed_order','adding_customer_email_recipient_to_packed', 10, 2 );
    function adding_customer_email_recipient_to_packed( $recipient, $order ){
    if( is_admin() ) return $recipient;
      $billing_email = $order->get_billing_email();
      $recipient .= ', ' . $billing_email; 
    }
```

My Wordpress Version: 4.9.9
Woocommerce Version: 3.5

Please help me send the email. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48820439/add-new-order-status-and-send-email-notification-woocommerce

Comment: @developerme Thanks a lot. I am now able to send emails.

Comment: @developerme Just Upvoted. Do you know how to create custom email notification with woocommerce?

Comment: @SushangNirola Yes. just show what have you done. We will help